# Determine whether a MATLAB GUI edittextbox is is use

Tags: matlab, user-interface, textbox, edit, matlab-figure

Basically I have a really complex Matlab GUI, where the user can add different strings by an editextbox (the one you can type in). The problem is that I assigned different functions to different keyboard button pushdowns, for example 's' and 'e' are in use. Every time you try to type in for example 'snake' the functions assigned to 's' and 'e' are executed. Is there any way to determine wheter I clicked in the edittextbox, and it is in use -> like a logical value so i can block the keypressfunctions by checking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your callback, you can use `gco` to get the current object. You can then check if this is the graphics handle to your edit box.

```
fig = figure('WindowKeyPressFcn', @(s,e)keypress());

hedit = uicontrol('Style', 'edit');

function keypress()
    if ~isequal(gco, hedit)
        disp('Window Key Press')
    end
end
```

If on the other hand you didn't set a global key press callback (using `WindowKeyPressFcn`) and you instead set the `KeyPressFcn` of each `uicontrol` individually, just specifying a different (or no) `KeyPressFcn` for the edit box would work.

Comment: Thank you it worked!

My button callbacks were global.